# How can I revert a chmod on the etc directory?

Tags: linux, files, chmod

I accidentally executed the following command on the etc directory:

```
sudo chmod -R 700 /etc
```

I know that I have done something very wrong. My terminal now prints:

```
I have no name!@ubuntu: /$
```

How can I revert my etc directory to its earlier state?

I tried changing the permissions but it is failing now. Also, it would be very helpful if someone can explain what actually went wrong when I executed that command on etc. It was only file permissions. Then why does the whole system seems completely blown up? Why is it that no login passwords are working now? I know that there is a file in etc directory that has to do with users. But how did changing permissions jeopardize everything? Some technical details about this would be very helpful.

Comment: You need a directory listing (`ls -laR`) from another running system. What version is yours? You can change directories to 755 and and files to 644, but some must have different modes (like /etc/shadow e.g.).

Comment: When you type `sudo` you should read it back in your head as "I am granting myself ultimate power over my system with no safety net, am I sure I know what I'm doing? Am I certain that I typed what I meant?" before pressing return.

Comment: With a working system, you can use `find /etc -type d ! -perm 755 -exec ls -ld {} \;` and `find etc -type f ! -perm -644 -exec ls -l {} \;` to find directories and files with non-standard modes. In Debian it's just 2 directories and 39 files

Comment: "But how did changing permissions jeopardize everything?" - some things that needed to read those files now don't have permission to read those files.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One thing went wrong: the use of `sudo` with that command. The `-R` switch tells `chmod` to recursively set the permissions to that directory, which is, in every case, a non-recommended action (should we call it: heresy) if you don't know what are you doing (once this happened to me, I didn't issue the command but a faulty GUI made it, and my system went wire).

> It was only file permissions. Then why does the whole system seems completely blown up?

GNU/Linux is very sensitive to file permissions, as it was built with stability and **security** in mind. Same applies to most programs run in GNU/Linux (i.e. `apache2` drops root privileges and uses `www-data`, or similar user, and your `700` permission wouldn't allow it to read/write it own files).

> Why is it that no login passwords are working now?

As you already mention, login passwords are stored in a file in `/etc/passwd` and only root (I assume you didn't change that) can read it, but the login prompt (or GUI login) uses a non-privilege account, hence it cannot read the file.

> But how did changing permissions jeopardize everything?

Same as said above, Linux is very sensitive to file permissions. Some programs even check the permissions of their configuration files and if they are not expected they won't run at all.

> How can I revert my etc directory to its earlier state?

If you use a RPM-based distro, this can be done using the `rpm --setperms` command, it would be painfully reverting one by one the packages, on Debian-like system `apt-get --reinstall install` is your friend. Other solutions may be available, but would need a working system for it.

Answer (score 5):

Let's see, what you have done is set permissions in the whole /etc dir as read/write/execute allowed only for the owner of the file/dir, denied for everybody else. If you are confused by the file permissions, you can read more at [Wikipedia: Traditional UNIX permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions).

The reason you have blown up your system is because many processes can't read their settings anymore, being unable to access /etc. It won't be easy to recover the entire /etc dir to its previous state. How to do that will depend on your distro, but basically it means reinstalling every package which holds any file within /etc.

As a quick band aid to be able to use the system, in order to fix it properly (reinstalling all the packages with contents within /etc, as stated above), you could do:

```
    # sudo find /etc -type d -exec chmod 775 '{}' \;
    # sudo find /etc -type f -exec chmod 664 '{}' \;
```

With those two lines you'll be setting liberal permissions in all the /etc dir, with read/write allowed for the owner and the group, and read allowed for everybody else. The reason of the two chmod is to set the execute bit only on dirs. Some processes will complain or fail even so, including any executable within /etc, but you should be able to do the reinstall I outlined above.

Please be aware than until you recover the original permissions your system will be, at the very least, in an insecure state.

Comment: Additionally, some programs won't work; SSH for example requires restrictive permissions on certain files. `/etc/sudoers` is another.

Comment: But some files in `/etc` must not be made world readable ever! Restore from backups, that's why you have them (or, that's why people have been urging you to make backups).

Answer (score 0):

700 has removed access to lots of files for groups and world users (e.g. files now have `rwx------` permissions).  For example, all users need to be able to read `/etc/passwd`.  With your setup, only root can now read `/etc/passwd`.  Many things will break if you break the permissions on files in `/etc/` in unpredictable ways.

You could try and rebuild the permissions (assuming you can still switch to root) based on a working server, but that's prone to error.

I suggest restoring `/etc/` from backup if you have one (making sure the restore puts the permissions back, or, if your backup solution supports it, restore just the permissions).