# How can I revert the permissions of /etc? Whole system stopped working

Tags: centos, chmod, system-recovery

I am looking forward for this question.
[How can I revert a chmod on the etc directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84090/how-can-i-revert-a-chmod-on-the-etc-directory)

I have tried all the methods, but I am still not able to restore the permissions of my `/etc` directory.

```
sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXGrQ.png))

I also tried `apt-get --reinstall install`
but unfortunately I am getting:

```
-bash: apt-get: command not found
```

([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8XVR.png))

It will cause a great loss. How can I revert this?

Comment: Welcome on U&L! I took the liberty of editing your question because it's best to [avoid posting images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/315749) whenever possible. Also, you are using `apt-get`, the package manager of Debian and derivatives, but the question is tagged [tag:centos]: is there any reason for this? Which operating system (and version) are you using?

Comment: Your system should have a rescue DVD or other media. It can also be downloaded. Use it to repair your system or save your data.

Comment: Do you have a backup of `/etc`?   or were you using [etckeeper](https://etckeeper.branchable.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a record of what the permissions were before the changes were made, then you're out of luck. The permission on *that* folder are complex.

***IF*** you do have a record of the permissions, then you can restore them file-by-file, if you wish, after changing to root user by issuing the command:

```bsh
su root
```

I would just reinstall.

Comment: The package manager can usually be used (in rescue mode or similar) to restore or at least display the "factory default" permissions of each file in `/etc`, and restoring those is usually enough to restore basic system functionality. For RPM-based distributions, you could restore default permissions of all RPM-packaged files system-wide with `for p in $(rpm -qa); do rpm --setperms $p; done`. Then it'll be just a matter of re-implementing any local customizations to the permissions of `/etc`.

Comment: Didn't worked! I think we have to migrate it to new instance where we can change to user rather than root and revert back the permission.